# Pandas - Store a string json into column and write it to file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a few columns and one of them is a json string. When pandas write my dataframe to csv, it converts my JSON to a mess like `"{""account_sid"": ""AC68a8baf89872000218e9245b27367e3c"", ""actor_sid"": ""WSe666c5749a1903155a6235d9525a84a7"",..}"`

And when I'm gonna do a copy into redshift, it fails because of two double quotes. Why can't keep a plain text like `{"account_sid"": "AC68a8baf89872000218e9245b27367e3c", "actor_sid"": "WSe666c5749a1903155a6235d9525a84a7",..}`??

Here is how I'm parsing dict to json and writing df to csv:

```py
def _normalize_task_and_reservation_event(event):
    event_data = event.get('event_data')
    task_attrs = json.loads(event_data.get('task_attributes', '{ }').replace(';', ':'))
    worker_attrs = json.loads(event_data.get('worker_attributes', '{ }'))            
    event['event_date'] = event.get('event_date').isoformat()        
    return {
        'event_date': event.get('event_date'),
        'event_json': json.dumps(event).replace(';',':'),
        # 'event_json': event,
        'event_sid': event.get('sid'),
        'event_type': event.get('event_type'),
        'task_sid': event_data.get('task_sid'),
        'workflow_name': event_data.get('workflow_name'),
        'workspace_name': event_data.get('workspace_name'),
        'task_queue_name': event_data.get('task_queue_name'),
        'called': _extract_phone(task_attrs.get('called', '')),
        'caller': _extract_phone(task_attrs.get('caller', '')),
        'direction': task_attrs.get('direction', ''),
        'agent_email': worker_attrs.get('email', ''),
        'agent_name': worker_attrs.get('full_name', ''), 
        'zendesk_ticket_id': task_attrs.get('zendesk_ticket_id', '0'),
        'start_call_sid': task_attrs.get('call_sid', ''),
        'worker_sid': event_data.get('worker_sid', ''),
        'rounded_time': _round_up_time(event.get('event_date'))
    }


data = list(map(_normalize_task_and_reservation_event, events))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)    

# df['event_json'] = df.event_json.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x).replace(';',':') )
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=local_file, sep=';', index=False)
```

Comment: Is it correct you have 2 double quotes after each string? I mean `"account_sid""` instead of `"account_sid"` and `"actor_sid""` instead of `"actor_sid"`. It is better you post your whole program to be clear.

Comment: Already posted entire code that converts my data to dataframe. And yes, I have double quotes around my entire json!

Comment: so you basically want to write the json column as it is? like a simple string column?

Comment: Yes! I want a json as simple string, no two double quotes everywhere!